# helpers for all controllers under a namespace?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

I have an admin namespace. Is there a standard way to create a helper file that is automatically available for every controller in the namespace?

Answer (score 3):

If you have all your controllers in the namespace inherit from a different controller than the others in your application, say `Admin::AdminBaseController`, then this becomes simple. Just add the following line to that controller:

```
helper :all
```

Comment: not a bad solution. I ended up making an Admin::NamespaceHelper, and then doing include Admin::NamespaceHelper in ApplicationHelper. That way it's still modular, and I don't have to change the entire structure of the controllers (inheriting). Tho I'm not sure what the overhead costs are by doing this. Probably minimal.

Comment: Definitely minimal. You should answer your own question and mark it as closed. Thanks for the vote!

Comment: @pixelearth, you should answer your own question and either accept your answer or mine to help out the community. Thanks!